# Django to_python function being called on every database query

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am working on a web application that allows users to submit a form. Once the form has been submitted the `get_db_prep_value()` encrypts all the fields.  The bit I'm struggling with is the functionality that decrypts the fields in the django admin app. The decryption process works fine, the problem is that the decryption method that is specified in the to_python method is being called when the form is being submitted. My understanding of the to_python method was that it is only called when a database query is made from the database(select query) not to the database (update, insert).

Here is my custom field class:

```
class EncryptedField(models.Field):
    # ...

    def to_python(self, value):
        return decrypt(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        return encrypt(value)
```

How can I get the `to_python` method to be called only when the form is loaded within the django admin app on the change form page?

Comment: When the form is submitted and the server receives the data, it needs to bind an object to the form - i.e. get the object associated with the from from the database hence the to_python call you notice.

Comment: @pastylegs Thanks for the response. There's just one thing, I don't understand why an object needs to binded to the form for an insert. I can understand for an update or an insert where after it's inserted, the page reloads with the new object's data for viewing. Is that what you are referring to? Whereas in my case once the form is submitted a new form is loaded with empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

"The to_python() method on a Field is the first step in every validation."

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/